# mat-select and mat-dialog flickers on android device - Ionic 7 and angular 17

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently working on ionic project and used a angular framework but somehow mat-select and mat-dialog which is flickers fraction of seconds. as you can see in attachment.

**Ionic 7 & Angular 17 dependecies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/share": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  }
```

**global.scss**

```
/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/display.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import './assets/fonts/icons/material-icon.scss';
@import "@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Current Result:
[image: Android Real Device behaviour]

Have tried to set z-index for below class in global.scss

```
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";


.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper,
.cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

But nothing is working in real device.

Any help would be appreciated.